# AS3 hitTestObject will not register

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, hittest

Hey guys so basically i want to create mulltiple levels and i set up the levels as shown below but for some reason the HittestObject for level_2 is not initiating. I cant pinpoint what i am doing wrong. Level 2 is initiated but when i try to hit thee obect it just goes right through.

i have a Goal_1 and a goal_2 that i want to hittes with the player.

i want to have multiple levels with the goal_1 and multiple levels with the goal_2 and so on

Here is the Code:

```
public class keepFocusEngine extends MovieClip 
{


    //MultiTouch added for touch gestures
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;


    public var btnPressedUp:Boolean;
    public var btnPressedDown:Boolean;
    public var btnShootPlayer:Boolean;

    public var btnUp:MovieClip;
    public var btnDown:MovieClip;
    public var shootPlayer:MovieClip;

    private var speed:Number = 6.0;
    public var vx:Number = 0;
    public var vy:Number = 0;
    private var friction:Number = 0.93;
    private var maxspeed:Number = 12;


    public var player:mPlayer;
    public var mGoal_1:goal_1;
    public var mGoal_2:goal_2;

    public var playerLives:Number;
    public var livesText:TextField;

    public var highScoreText:TextField;
    public var nScore:Number;

    public var levelText:TextField;
    public var nLevel:Number;

    public var menuEnd:mcEndGameScreen;
    public var menuStart:mcStartGameScreen;






    public function keepFocusEngine() 
    {
        //Initialize variable to false
        btnDown.visible = false;
        btnUp.visible = false;
        shootPlayer.visible = false;
        livesText.visible = false;
        highScoreText.visible = false;
        levelText.visible = false;



        //Create loader object
        var startGameLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        //Add event listener for complete event
        startGameLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startGameLoaded);
        //Load loader object
        startGameLoader.load(new URLRequest("StartGameScreen.swf"));

        //Create End game loader object
        var endGameLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        //Add event listener
        endGameLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, endGameLoaded);
        //Load end game object
        endGameLoader.load(new URLRequest("EndGameScreen.swf"));



    }

    private function startGameLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        //Get a refrece to the loaded movieclip
        menuStart = e.target.content as mcStartGameScreen;
        //Listen for start game event
        menuStart.addEventListener("START_GAME", playGameAgain);
        //Add start screen to the stage
        addChild(menuStart);
    }

    private function endGameLoaded(e:Event):void 
    {
        menuEnd = e.target.content as mcEndGameScreen;
        menuEnd.addEventListener("END_GAME", playGameAgain);
        addChild(menuEnd);
        menuEnd.hideEndScreen();
    }

    private function playGameAgain(e:Event):void 
    {



        //Add Hi Res Stats
        addChild(new Stats());

        //mainPlayerObject added to stage
        player = new mPlayer();
        stage.addChild(player);
        player.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 280;
        player.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        mGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        stage.addChild(mGoal_1);







        //Update Player lives and add 3 lives
        playerLives = 3;
        updatePlayerLives();


        //Update Level progression
        nLevel = 1;
        updatePlayerLevel();


        //Add score to texxt field
        nScore = 0;
        updateHighScore();

        //Initialize stage objects to true 
        btnDown.visible = true;
        btnUp.visible = true;
        shootPlayer.visible = true;
        livesText.visible = true;
        highScoreText.visible = true;
        levelText.visible = true;

        //Hide external screens
        menuEnd.hideEndScreen();
        menuStart.hideStartScreen();



        //setup Listeners when btn's are rolled over and out
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OVER, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true); 
        btnUp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, btnUpMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        btnDown.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OVER, btnDownMouseOver, false, 0, true); 
        btnDown.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT, btnDownMouseOver, false, 0, true);
        shootPlayer.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, shootPlayerObject, false, 0, true);

        //setup game loop event listeners
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);



        //To completely end game when back button pushed on android
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown );


    }

    private function gameLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        playerShoot();
        playerControl();
        playerStageBoundaries();

        checkEndGameCondition();
        checkPlayerOffScreen();

        level_1();
    }


    private function level_1():void 
    {


        if(player.hitTestObject(mGoal_1))
           {

            trace("Goal_1 Collision");
            //Remove button for constant movement
            btnShootPlayer = false;
            mGoal_1.destroyGoal_1();
            player.destroyPlayer();
            //Update High Score text
            nScore += 10;
            updateHighScore();

            //Update level
            nLevel++;
            updatePlayerLevel();
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            level_2();




           }else
           {

               checkEndGameCondition();
           }
    }



    public function level_2():void 
    {
       stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
        trace("Level_2 Initiated");
        //Keep Text Scores initiated
        updateHighScore();
        updatePlayerLives();

        player = new mPlayer();
        stage.addChild(player);
        player.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 280;
        player.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        mGoal_1 = new goal_1();
        stage.addChild(mGoal_1);







        if (player.hitTestObject(mGoal_1))
        {
            trace("Level 2 Hit test works!");


            nScore += 10;
            updateHighScore();

        }



    }
```

Comment: Your Level_1 function calls the Level_2 function when the player hits the goal, however Level_2 does not get called every frame like Level_1. So the only time the program checks for a hitTest in Level_2 is when the player hits the first goal.

Comment: Thats what i thought was going on I've been doig a lot of research and countless hours of recoding on how to fix this but i just cant get it right.  I understand that i would need to add it to my gameLoop(); enterFrame event but that would call both of them at the same time every frame. So im trying to figure out how to call them after each hittest if statement is met as you can see from above. Do i need to add a eventListener for level2 and 3 and so on? or is their an easier method that you may be able to point me to?

Comment: I'm currently in class but when I get back to my house and my computer I'll edit my answer with an example of how to do what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds great thanks so much for taking the time to help. I was working on it last night and made a little progress. I deleted the goal_2 and kept the goal_1 for now since i couldnt get goal 2 to hit. It worked and level_2 hittest was traced but the only problem was i couldnt get the MovieClips to be destroyed. But yeah ill just wait for your help and post my updated code. I would love to use multiple Goals  Thats why i have Goal_1 and Goal_2 so on.

Comment: Nevermind thought i made some progress but back to the start :/

Comment: Hey Henly you still their???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it's taken so long for me to get back to you.

Here is an example of how to set up your levels...

#### gameLoop()

I would just add a switch statement in there to let the gameLoop know which level function to update every frame. The switch statement is like an if...if else conditional with less typing. The output of the switch statement is decided by the comparison of `nLevel` with the possible cases. So, when `nLevel` equals 1, the `level_1()` function is executed. By adding to `nLevel` we can then update `level_2()` and so on.

```
    private function gameLoop(e:Event):void
    {
        playerShoot();
        playerControl();
        playerStageBoundaries();

        checkEndGameCondition();
        checkPlayerOffScreen();

        switch(nLevel) {
            case 1:
                level_1();
                break;
            case 2:
                level_2();
                break;
        }
    }
```

#### startNextLevel()

This function is used to remove the repetetive code in your level functions, just call this function and it will reset player position and update the score and level.

```
    private function startNextLevel():void
    {
        nScore += 10;
        updateHighScore();

        nLevel++;
        updatePlayerLevel();

        updatePlayerLives();

        player.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 280;
        player.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
    }
```

#### Level Functions

These are your level functions, instead of adding the player to the stage each level, just reuse the player and reset it's position.

```
    private function level_1():void
    {

        if (player.hitTestObject(mGoal_1))
        {

            trace("Goal_1 Collision");
            //Remove button for constant movement
            btnShootPlayer = false;
            mGoal_1.destroyGoal_1();
            player.destroyPlayer();

            startNextLevel();
        }
        else
        {
            checkEndGameCondition();
        }
    }

    private function level_2():void
    {
        //Keep Text Scores initiated


        if (player.hitTestObject(mGoal_2))
        {   
            mGoal_2.destroyGoal_2();
            player.destroyPlayer();

            btnShootPlayer = false;
            startNextLevel();
        } else {
            checkEndGameCondition();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I didnt event think about a switch Statement. I will definitely try this out today. Thanks for the detail coding man i really appreciate it! Ill let you know how it goes!